# What's the best way to count and score text in a mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Having a collection of {_id: 'xxx', text: 'abc'}

What is the best way to have a list of entities with the same text, considering also spelling mistakes, for example 'gogle' 'google' ordered by the number of similar entities?

Answer (score 0):

mongodb doesn't have the capability to find misspelled items. there are some thirdparty libraries/plugins that offer this feature by storing [double metaphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone) key codes along with the original version of the text. here's an [example program](https://gist.github.com/dj-nitehawk/14ae67d8169c7185876a87503d8b6007) in c# that gets the result you want. see [this page](https://mongodb-entities.com/wiki/Indexes-Fuzzy-Text-Search.html#how-it-works) for a brief explainer on how it works. if you're not coding in c#, there's [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-fuzzy-searching) for mongoose.

Comment: what about https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#sort-by-text-search-score

Comment: @Andrea > the $text operator matches on the complete stemmed word. So if a document field contains the word blueberry, a search on the term blue will not match. However, blueberry or blueberries will match.

Comment: @Andrea so it won't match `google` to `goggle` for sure. i believe they sell this functionality in mongodb atlas though. but it's gonna cost you.